# using valueLink, child input field unable to change

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to play with reactjs, and for this project, I have ->

- an input field
- a button that toggles a modal

  - the modal has another input field.

**How do we make both input fields stay in sync?**

What I though I would need to do use to use the LinkedState mixin.

So, I do something like this ->

```
MainFoo = React.createClass
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin]
  getInitialState: ->
    searchTerm: ''
  render: ->
    input valueLink: @linkState('searchTerm') # this works
    CustomReactChild
      searchTermLink: @linkState('searchTerm') #passing into child.

CustomReactChild = React.createClass
  renderModal:
    unless @modal
      $anchor = $('<div>').appendTo('body');
      comp = (Modal 
               body: (CustomReactChildchild 
                         searchTermLink: @props.searchTermLink)
             ) #custom react modal class
      @modal = React.renderComponent comp, anchor
    @modal.show()
  render: ->
    label
      onClick: @renderModal
# Deep inside CustomReactChild
CustomReactChildsChild = React.createClass
  render: ->
    input valueLink: @props.searchTermLink # Am unable to change the value via this input
```

Am I using this incorrectly? How can I get the second input to change the value of the parent's input and vice versa?

Comment: Does searchTermLink get passed down from CustomReactChild to CustomReactChildsChild at each level?

Comment: Hey Douglas, yes, but in a slightly wacky way. Just updated how CustomReactChild looks

Comment: Looking at the logs here, http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/3602/ - I think part of the problem is that the modal popup is re-rendering (or at least running the "Controlled Input" handler) before MainFoo has updated its state. I'd suggest merging the models together, so that there is only one `React.renderComponent` call, or factor out the state into a shared Store which both inputs update and get change events from.

Comment: Hey Douglas, thanks! The single renderComponent fixed the issue. I think your comments is worthy of an awesome answer. If you'd pop it in as an answer I'd love to give you the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Douglas popped in an awesome answer in the comments -->

> Looking at the logs here, jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/3602 - I think part of the problem is that the modal popup is re-rendering (or at least running the "Controlled Input" handler) before MainFoo has updated its state. I'd suggest merging the models together, so that there is only one React.renderComponent call, or factor out the state into a shared Store which both inputs update and get change events from. 
>   ```